# Emulate an IP Camera

Tags: streaming, ffmpeg, ip, rtp

I am using software (`DVR`) that is meant to talk directly to an IP camera. I am trying to pass a **h264** stream directly into it, but it does not work if I just throw a stream onto it.

Can you recommend any "spoofing" software to emulate an IP camera? For the sake of argument, we can say that the camera we want to emulate is `Axis P3301`.

Given that a lot of software out there can talk to IP cameras, is there a way to use something like `vlc/ffmpeg` to look like its an IP camera ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which "receiver" software are you using, and which platform (OS + hardware) would that camera be emulated on? You should also provide a few real IP camera models that are compatible with your software.

Comment: Have you tried just copying what ever transaction occurs with a real ip camera? like an axis camera or something.

Comment: @michael: Yes, that's what I am going to do. I was wondering if maybe something like this already exists out there.

Comment: Did you try reading the manual? I am sure the error here: "I am trying to pass a h264 stream directly into it" is that the camera is not sneding a H264 stream to start with. What it sends and how shuld be documented. Cameras are not all made the same.

Comment: @TomTom: I was not using a camera, but a h264 stream that I generated with vlc. I'm pretty sure that it was sending a H.264 stream considering I told it to :)

Comment: Yes, you did. But who knows whether the camera was doing so. If you want to emulatte a camrea and send a stream the camera does not, you dort of do noemulatei t at all, you know. And I doubt a normal IP camera has a H264 compressor chip in it.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. That's kind of my problem to start with. The camera's manual _says_ it provides h264 (which these days is pretty standard) but I can't know what's going on behind the scenes. In either case this problem is done and forgotten :)

Comment: @TomTom, most IP cameras have H.264 compressors in them and have for several years.  116 of the 119 Axis models support H.264.  Only three very old models don't and are still MPEG-4 Part 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Axis IP cameras provide video through RTSP.  Any RTSP server can be used to spoof the video aspect of an IP camera.

Examples:

> **Streaming with VLC**
>
> 1. Open VLC
> 2. Select Media > Stream
> 3. Select source media, then click "Stream"
> 4. Click "next" to confirm the source
> 5. Under "New Destination" select "RTSP"
> 6. Deselect "Activate Transcoding" (make sure your source is h264/aac)
> 7. Click Add.
> 8. Select port and path to mimick the camera. Port is usually 554 but path varies by camera model.
> 9. Click Stream

Now you can connect with your DVR software.

Note that Axis cameras also have APIs to pant/tilt/zoom and set options like resolution and bitrate.  You won't be able to emulate that.

Another good option is the Axis SDK that's available as part of their Application Development Partner program.  The SDK includes software that will mimic an Axis camera perfectly.  To join you fill out some paperwork and talk to a representative, but there's no cost and if you're working with Axis there are a ton of benefits.

http://www.axis.com/partner/adp_program/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fully emulate an Axis camera, there is a free software provided by Axis which allows you to do it with all the functionalities. It is mandatory to have that camera just one time to create the virtual camera template.
[Axis Virtual Camera Download](ftp://ftp.axis.com/pub_soft/cam_srv/Temp/AVC/3.05.001/)

Comment: "Fully emulate" - well, for Axis camera's from 2010. There are newer versions, but as Samuel Neff already mentioned you need to be an Axis Application Development Partner (ADP) to get those.

Comment: Hi, Would this Axis tool work with AXIS Q6010-E Network Camera. I am trying since many days to make it work. I enabled only basic auth on camera as well as I found that Axis tool needs only basic auth. That also did not solve the issue. I have an older Axis 214 camera which works just fine with this tool. I just wanted to know if this Axis tool supports new QUAD cameras by Axis in Q6000 series.